# Spring MVC WebContentInterceptor no-cache for static content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

Using WebContentInterceptor I've enabled caching mechanism on the client side.

But as you can see, some of the folders under parent (resources/) folder should 
 be cached and some others should not be be...

At first I've just used this configuration;

```
<mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/resources/**" />

        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/js/project/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/css/project/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/images/users/**" />

        <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="2592000" />
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

As you can follow my logic, I've cached all of the folders but excluded the ones doesn't need to be.
But it didn't work. So I've configured something like this.

```
<mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/resources/js/project/**" />
        <mvc:mapping path="/resources/css/project/**" />
        <mvc:mapping path="/resources/images/users/**" />

        <bean id="webContentInterceptorNoCache"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/resources/**" />

        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/js/project/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/css/project/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/images/users/**" />

        <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="2592000" />
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

Thinking that the first interceptor could just remove cachings. But it also didn't work.

And I even tried this to see no-cache header

```
 <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/resources/**" />

        <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

Still no chance.

Am I doing something wrong ? Can you help me ?